# Why are there numbers next to my personal device name in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I first started testing applications on my device (an iPhone XR), it just showed "[My Name]'s iPhone." Now, however, it has some numbers in parentheses next to that. I've never come across this before and was wondering if there is some sort of problem, or if everything is okay.

[Screenshot of what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T5Ym.png)

Comment: Open up the Simulators window and take a peek in there to see if anything looks out of place. Have you recently updated XCode?

Comment: @Trlewi The simulators look fine to me...and I haven't updated Xcode in a little while.

Comment: That looks like a pid (process ID)

Comment: @MatteoPacini why would a PID get appended to the name my iPhone is set to on the actual device?

Comment: I have no idea!

Comment: @MatteoPacini that's so odd! Well, if it alters my device name again, then I'll check it out further...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the cause was, but I found out that it was also happening in iTunes. It may have something to do with getting a new phone.

Anyway, the name on my phone was somehow changed, so I just went to edit it on my phone in:

**Settings > General > About > Name**